# Django rest auth user_logged_in signal

Tags: python, django, rest, django-allauth, django-signals

I have a django rest app using django rest auth.
I'm trying to log something everytime a user log in using signals.

I've searched on the web on how to use signals and I haven't found any interesting material on how to make it work. I think the problem may be with allauth signals. Is there any problem with the following configuration?

**signals.py**

```
import logging

from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def login_logger(request, user, **kwargs):
    logger.info("{} logged in with {}".format(user.email, request))
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

**__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I solved it using `djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0`:

settings.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user=None, request=None):
    if user and request:
        user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
    return {
        'token': token,
    }

JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER': jwt_response_payload_handler,
}
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in

def login_handler(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    print('logged in')

user_logged_in.connect(login_handler)
```

Comment: It worked for me as well. Thanks. However, better also mention that 'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication' needs to be added to the REST_FRAMEWORK variable in settings.py

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Django Rest Framework doesn't emit `user_logged_in` signal when token-based authentication is configured: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3869

Answer (score 2):

For future googlers. The OP's original question was that he wanted to log something everytime a user logs in when using rest_auth. You would expect a signal to be emitted by rest_auth for something like this but rest_auth does different things depending on the type of login. For a session login, rest_auth calls into django's normal login routines and a signal does get emitted. But for token-based authentication, rest_auth creates the token and returns it and there is no call into django proper and no signal is emitted. 
Here's the rest_auth [login code](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/624ad01afbc86fa15b4e652406f3bdcd01f36e00/rest_auth/views.py#L61)

To get the behavior you want, you have to override rest_auth's [default token handler](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/624ad01afbc86fa15b4e652406f3bdcd01f36e00/rest_auth/utils.py#L14) (it's straightforward) so you know when a token gets created and then log the event however you want.

In django's settings.py file add:

`REST_AUTH_TOKEN_CREATOR = '<your_dotted_project_path>.create_login_token'`

In some file in your project:

```
# this is the same as the default rest_auth token handler except we
# don't throw away the 'created' part because we care whether it was
# created or just retrieved.
def create_login_token(token_model, user, serializer):
    token, created = token_model.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    if created:
        >>> log it or emit your own signal or whatever <<<

    return token
```

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason, this doesn't seem to work when placed in `signals.py`, this implementation of `signals.py` works fine for every part of project except for `allauth`(I had my personal experience too). Check this github issueshttps://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/347

For some strange reason moving this code(`signals.py`) into `models.py` of the same app will work.

```
# place this in models.py
from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def login_logger(request, user, **kwargs):
    logger.info("{} logged in with {}".format(user.email, request))
```

Comment: Am I missing some configuration stuff?

Comment: all looks good for me, can you just make sure logger for `users` app is configired in settings (just to make sure ), otherwise I dont see any reason why it shouldnt work

Comment: place this in  `models.py` , and restart the local server, it should work

Comment: I already tried to move the code to `model.py` and it doesn't work. I think the problem may be in allauth configuration beacuse I tried to debug it and it never hit any of the receivers... Then I tried to add request_finished receiver and that worked. So I think the problem is with allaurh signals, but the documentation is so poor.

Comment: Since the update to dajngo 3.2, this regression has been solved. Now it is working as desired when placing these functions into a signal.py either.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't pick up from `signals.py` for some strange reason. However, you can still maintain the separation of concerns using the following. This worked for me while still keeping the signal logic away from my models.

**signals.py**

```
import logging

from allauth.account.signals import user_logged_in
from django.dispatch import receiver

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def login_logger(request, user, **kwargs):
    logger.info("{} logged in with {}".format(user.email, request))
```

**models.py**

```
from .signals import *

// Your models here

class Foo(models.Model):
    pass
```

Comment: Since the update to dajngo 3.2, this regression has been solved. Now it is working as desired when placing these functions into a signal.py either.